# What KML features are suitable to display 3D atmospheric density data using Google Earth?

Tags: kml, 3d, google-earth, 3d-map

I wish to use Google Earth to visualise and explore 3D atmospheric density data. In my case it is ionospheric electron density, which is a niche area, but I can imagine this might have been done by someone to display say atmospheric moisture content or pollution levels (or volcanic ash plumes??).

I am new to KML files, but reading over the developer guide it isn't obvious how best to go about this. Would you slice your 3D density data into many 2D layers and use < altitude > elements? Or would it be better to use grid the data into many small cubes and use < polygon >s? Or some other option?

I'm sure this has been done before, but I couldn't find any suitable examples.

Comment: What sort of format is your 3D data in? My first thought was Sketch Up, not sure if it would be useful but you can put 3D models of building in with it, so I would think you could put things above ground too.

Comment: I have a parametrised model describing the 3D density field. I can output this into any required format.

Comment: It might be useful if you can describe why you want to visualise it? Are you just trying for nice pictures, or are you trying to find "something" over time, or over distance, or over altitude? What is the "something" that your visualisation is aimed to explore?

Comment: You might also consider [Nasa Worldwind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov) that is designed for such kind of overlays, as this example of Wifis present: https://wiki.opennet-initiative.de/wiki/Benutzer:Thm/Blog:2011_January_20_09:55:17_CET

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

http://docs.geoserver.org/2.2.4/user/googleearth/features/kmlheighttime.html

But you will have to put this in a geo-database, like postgres.

I've managed something simular, with building geometrie. In the database the geometrie was a multipolygon. In one column I set the height parametervield.

You could do the same with pointfeatures and also timeparameter....